# PlaneBufferGeometry isn't displayed with orthographic camera

Tags: three.js

I have a `PlaneBufferGeometry` that isn't displayed when I switch from a `PerspectiveCamera` to a `OrthographicCamera`. Other objects like `Box2D` work fine with both cameras.

Is ortographic camera not able to render planes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthographic cameras can render planes, but since planes have no thickness, they will generally be "invisible" if the plane points up or down, for example, if it represents a floor. This is the nature of the orthographic camera: its field of view doesn't differ with depth, and it doesn't offer perspective.